# Which java compiler is used by NetBeans?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, netbeans

If I tell NetBeans (6.9) to compile on save, NetBeans warns me the compiled classes are not identical to classes compiled with JDK's compiler. The Java platform is set to "JDK 1.6" in the same dialog. Which compiler is used by NetBeans? Why doesn't NetBeans use the JDK compiler?

[alt text http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/3449/compileonsave.png](http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/3449/compileonsave.png)

Comment: Can't you set NetBeans to use your installed SDK? Don't forget that NetBeans and Java are now owned by Oracle, so basically a NetBeans SDK is actually a java SDK.

Answer (score 5):

Like Eclipse, Netbeans does not use standard `javac` so that it can offer incremental compilation and compilation of classes containing methods that have syntax errors.

Unlike Eclipse (which uses its own Eclipse Java Compiler), Netbeans actually uses **the internal API of javac** for compiling, syntax highlighting, and error detection. This is a nice advantage, in that Netbeans is able to handle all of the latest Java language features and faithfully reproduces any nuances or bugs of javac's behavior.

sources:

- http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Digging-into-the-NetBeans-Java-Editor
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't NetBeans use the JDK compiler?

Quite simply because Sun's `javac` is intended to be used for batch-based compilation from the command line of definitively valid files.  Whereas NetBeans (and other IDEs) do incremental compilation as you type, and quite often have additional features such as creating classes for invalid files (so you can run `methodA` if `methodB` has a syntax error in, etc.).

Different tools for different requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Java Platform Manager : Tools->Java Platforms

Comment: There is nothing about the compiler, but about libraries like rt.jar.

Answer (score 0):

at Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\etc there is a netbeans_jdkhome value.

Comment: It is set to `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"`, my default JDK. If this is the relevant setting, NetBeans should be using the default compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Quite some time since question was asked, but I guess that what your looking for:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave