# Why does this statement work in Java?

Tags: java

I accidentally wrote something like this on NetBeans:

```
System.out.println(("Apples") System.out.println("Oranges"));
```

It initially showed me no error, compiled and the output was:

```
Apples
Oranges
```

After running it started showing me an error but it still compiled and gave the same output.

Also, is `System.out.println((grade/=3) + "%")` a valid statement?

**EDIT:** As people are saying that it is not compiling, here is a screenshot:
http://s1.postimg.org/m1ezmm3vz/Untitled.png
It is compiling for me :/

Comment: `System.out.println(("Apples") System.out.println("Oranges"));` is showing compile time error http://ideone.com/lJPxYl  and `System.out.println((grade/=3) + "%")` is like  `System.out.println((grade =grade/3) + "%")` and its valid http://ideone.com/Mk2K71

Comment: doesn't work compile error for me

Comment: Considering grade as a int or float variable, `System.out.println((grade/=3) + "%")` is a valid statement.

Comment: Are you sure it compiled? If compilation failed you might be running an older version of the code (the last one that did compile). - Don't know if netbeans works like that or not...

Comment: i dont know about netbeans but in eclipse its showing compile time error...!!!
are you sure its working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is valid:

```
System.out.println((grade/=3) + "%");
```

Here the `(grade/=3)` is calculated first and then `%` is appended.

But the

```
System.out.println(("Apples") System.out.println("Oranges"));
```

is invalid statement. For this case compiler generates compilation errors like :

```
error: ')' expected
error: illegal start of expression
error: ';' expected
```

Answer (score 0):

The first statement does not compile or execute in Eclipse or using Command Line options.
Similar queries have been answered in this thread for Netbeans compiler

[Which java compiler is used by NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364638/which-java-compiler-is-used-by-netbeans)